# Managing a server over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, openssh

I am running a Minecraft server on Fedora 15. I have openssh-server installed on the server and I can connect to it just fine.

Right now, the Minecraft server software opens into a terminal when the user logs in. The server software has a console that accepts commands and prints status updates and stuff like that. I am wondering if there is a way that I can access that already-running server console remotely over SSH.

Comment: Heh.  Looks like everyone loves screen.  I think Dolda2000 was first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `screen`.  You'll find it in the package manager.

So start a screen session, then start the minecraft server.

Next time you ssh to the box, you can `screen -r` and it will bring the session back.

Comment: Is there any way that I can detach a screen session running locally on the machine while I am using ssh?

Comment: If you have a prompt, you can type ```screen -d```.  If you are running something, you can type ctrl-a-d.  Also, just ending your ssh session will leave the screen session running in a detached state.  If you use linux command line more than a little, you really want to get into using ```screen```.  It will make you happy.  Look online for .screenrc examples.  ```screen``` can run multple concurrent bash shells that you can switch between, which saves running multiple ssh sessions - and they all survive a logout-login.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is a command line program, consider running it in a screen session.

e.g.:

```
$ screen
$ minecraft-server-program
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to detach from the session. From an ssh session, type in `screen -r` to resume the screen session.

Answer (score 0):

Start it in an instance of GNU `screen`. `screen` is basically a terminal multiplexer, which maintains one or several virtual terminals that you can switch between, and the whole set of virtual terminals can be reattached in a new login.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here to provide an alternative!

Use `tmux`.

Install it with `yum install tmux`.

Like `screen`, run your server after starting a new `tmux` session like so.

```
$ tmux
$ ./minecraftserver
```

The prefix key for `tmux` is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. After starting your Minecraft server, you can detach from the current session with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>. Your Minecraft server will continue to run in the `tmux` session.

To attach back into the `tmux` session, type `tmux att` from your normal shell.

If you have more than one `tmux` sessions open, type `tmux list-sessions`, which will give you something like this.

```
[jin@encrypt ~] % tmux list-sessions
0: 1 windows (created Fri Sep 30 10:24:23 2011) [179x43]
1: 1 windows (created Fri Sep 30 10:28:29 2011) [179x43]
```

If you want to go back to the second session, type `tmux att -t 1`.

For more commands and configuration options, see [here](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/).

Comment: While this isn't really a place for chatting - do you know the pros and cons versus ```screen```?  ```Ctrl-b``` is one already, but I could always remap ```ctrl-a``` in ```screen``` if it bothered me enough.

Comment: @Paul Why does it bother you? I've actually remapped `tmux`'s prefix key from `b` to `a`. Anyway, you can check out this Unix.SE question for the comparison. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549/tmux-vs-gnu-screen

Comment: Some of the console apps I use from time to time need ctrl-a - but not frequently enough to make it worthwhile, I just work around it normally.